# Using GrabPass for 2D water reflection?

Tags: unity, shaders

I'm trying to achieve some neat 2d water reflection effect with Unity, something like this:
[image]

What I've managed to accomplish so far:

[image]

The problem is [GrabPass](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-GrabPass.html) captures the entire screen but I really want to control precisely what area of the screen will be captured.

Is it feasible with GrabPass? (I'd rather not use a new camera for a rendertexture).

Is that even the right approach?

Comment: What you can do is offset the UV Coordinates when sampling the GrabPass texture to zone in on just a portion of it in your shader. Or use another Camera with a set view rect... which you already specified you don't want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Grab Pass can work, in 2d. But what you need to do  is project the texture into screen space.

Here is the code you should use:

```
float4 reflectionTex = tex2D(_GrabTexture, float2(IN.screenPos.x, 1-IN.screenPos.y)/IN.screenPos.w).xyzw);
```

Comment: That should work, theoretically at least. Here we're first getting the screen-space coordinates of the pixel. This used directly will lead to the shader showing what is directly behind it. But IMO *only the y-coordinate* should be flipped (one minus), and not the x.

Answer (score 1):

[2D Water Reflection](http://u3d.as/u8a) can achieve results like that. I did it first for a friend who wanted exactly the same effect that you described and that is looking like [Kingdom](https://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=40539.20). I did not used GrabPass but a specific render texture instead. The result is then applied on a screen aligned quad, flipped, Y clipped and distorded. I do not know which one is performing better but I suspect they should be close.

[image]